# Automatically refresh only changed content after change in database

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have page where the user has the option to choose between design 'A' or 'B' etc.. with a 'on click' made with Jquery/AJAX.
I have a `foreach` that listens to what the user chooses, and outputs accordingly into a div.

**My question is:** How would I be able to make it so, that it is only the content that is being changed, that refreshes instantly, so the user can easily switch between design 'A', 'B' or 'C'?

This is what I have now that refreshes the whole site...

```
$("#presetchange2").on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/presethandler2.php",
        success: function(){
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
});
```

**The PHP i use**

```
<?php
$query = "
        SELECT
                dashboard_presets.includes AS includes
                FROM dashboard
                INNER JOIN dashboard_presets
                ON dashboard.preset = dashboard_presets.preset
                WHERE user_id = $user_id
    ";
try
{
    // Runs query to DB
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
```

**and**

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <?php echo $row['includes']; ?>
   </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: can you post your php??

Comment: Hi, sorry about that.. I added the PHP

Answer (score 0):

Well if you make your server return a partial of only the markup you need to replace the preset you can do something like:

```
$("#presetchange2").on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/presethandler2.php",
        success: function(html){
            $('#targetElement').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Where targetElement is the id of the element you are trying to fill.